# postgresql - how to use a cursor or select statement to generate mulitple DML statements

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

New to postgres and I'm using Postgresql 9.3. Is there a way with postgresql to generate a file with multiple DML statements?

For example, I want to select table name where tablename like `'_foo%'` and then rename all those tables to `'_bar%'`.  Do I need to do this in a **cursor** or can I do this within a **select statement**? (like in Oracle)

```
ALTER TABLE RENAME tst1_foo TO tst1_bar;
ALTER TABLE RENAME tst2_foo TO tst2_bar;
ALTER TABLE RENAME tst3_foo TO tst3_bar;
```

I'd like to print those out to a .sql file.

Please provide a basic example if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use psql and the [pg_tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/view-pg-tables.html) system view. Set the output to unaligned mode:

```
\a
```

Set the output to show only rows:

```
\t on
```

Send output to your file:

```
\o yourfile.sql
```

Run the query:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE RENAME ' || tablename || ' TO ' ||
  REGEXP_REPLACE ( tablename, '_foo$', '_bar' ) || ';'
FROM pg_tables
WHERE tablename LIKE '%_foo';
```

Close the file:

```
\o
```

*and/or* close psql:

```
\q
```

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was going for. Thanks!